# Neo4j configure parallel or serial operations?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can i configure if i want parallel or serial operation on my neo4j-community version database? I have different clients that fire queries and alter the nodes i would prefer serial transmission to prevent deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of APOC procedures that can perform operations in parallel.

For example, [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_transaction_batching).

You can search for the word "parallel" in the [APOC documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) to find other procedures that might be useful as well.